# How to SCP from Linux server to Windows client

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, putty, scp

I'm SSHing into a Linux machine using PuTTY and trying to copy a file down somewhere (anywhere) to my local machine. I *figure* SCP is the best candidate for the job but don't really care, so long as the solution works!

I `cd` to the directory containing the file I want (`app.war`) and type the following:

```
scp app.war ./
```

I've tried both to no avail:

```
scp app.war ./C:/Users/myUser/
scp app.war ./Users/myUser/
```

It got me thinking that perhaps SCP is a client/server tool and requires a client on my Windows machine, which isn't there.

Am I just using the wrong syntax? Or am I way off-base? If so, what options do I have?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The real answer to this question is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23412501/1579667 . Syntax is `scp some_file user@host:/c/temp`

Comment: Also see [Bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/) SSH client and server. It is one of the oldest SSH software for Windows. The client is a free download and free to use.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

in order for you to copy files back to your Windows you need SSH daemon/service to be running on your Windows, it's much easier to use this tool instead, it has an ability to import sessions from Putty, very plain forward client you'll love it!

[WinSCP :: Free SFTP and FTP client for Windows](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Comment: It does not really answer the original question, which was living in the command-line. See my comment below original question.

Comment: @Benj OP asked for solution, `WinSCP` is a good solution for that task.

Comment: It still works, but WinSCP tends to freeze up for directories with a lot of files

Answer (score 22):

Windows 10 now has OpenSSH built in.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

#### Get an admin command prompt

```
Open PowerShell as an Administrator.
```

#### Check available versions

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'
```

#### Install client

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
```

#### Install server

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

#### Start server and enable at boot

```
Start-Service sshd
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
```

#### Find your Windows IP address

```
ipconfig
```

#### On your remote (Linux) machine, find your IP address.

```
ifconfig
```

#### Create a public SSH key

```
ssh-keygen.exe
```

#### Copy public key from local (Windows) to remote (Linux) machine so you don't have to type in a password all the time.

#### Note that ssh-copy-id is not currently available on Windows.

```
cat C:\Users\YOU/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh USER@REMOTE_IP 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

#### Do the same on your Linux machine (Note, ssh-copy-id does not work)

```
ssh-keygen # if needed
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh USER@WINDOWS_IP 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh && type con >> C:/Users/YOU/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

- The method above did not work for me, so I ended up manually SCPing the public key over and pasting it into the C:/Users/YOU/.ssh/authorized_keys file.
- That still did not work, so I had to modify the sshd_config file.

  - Open Notepad as Administrator
  - Open %programdata%\ssh\sshd_config
  - Add the following lines:

```
        Match User YOU
             AuthorizedKeysFile C:/Users/YOU/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

- Reboot

#### Create a password on Windows if you don't already have one

```
System Settings...Sign-in options
```

-- Note, you can still disable the Windows login screen by a) Setting the 'Require sign-in' option to never and b) Using the 'netplwiz' command and unticking the 'Users must enter password...' checkbox.

#### Now you should be able to SSH or SCP from your Linux machine

```
scp FILE WINDOWS_IP:C:/Users/YOU/Desktop
```

Comment: This bit of syntax is what I came looking for;
scp FILE WINDOWS_IP:C:/Users/YOU/Desktop
  thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You are correct. SSHD is the SSH server services that runs on the host. It accepts connections from SSH clients (like PuTTy), SCP clients, and SFTP clients.

You can download `pscp` from the same website where [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) is hosted.

From the windows machine, you would execute a command similar to

`pscp.exe someuser@somehost.com:/path/to/app.war c:\tmp`

Answer (score 4):

To SCP a file to a Windows machine, you need an SSH/SCP server on the Windows.

Since Windows 10, Microsoft build of [OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) is included. It can also be manually installed on older versions of Windows.

I have prepared a guide for setting up [SSH/SFTP server on Windows using this Microsoft build of OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server).

See also [Is IIS SFTP natively supported by Windows?](https://serverfault.com/q/648855/168875#648865)

---

Though as you SSH into the Linux server from the Windows machine, you actually can download a file from the Linux server to the Windows server, instead of trying to upload the file from the Linux server to Windows server.

In you have an SSH access from Windows to Linux, you have an SCP access too (or even better an SFTP access).

Use any SCP/SFTP client available.

You can use [WinSCP SFTP/SCP client](https://winscp.net/), which has both [GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/screenshots) and [command-line interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting).

Another alternative is PuTTY toolset, which includes the [`pscp` command-line tool](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) with a syntax similar to the OpenSSH `scp` command. Also the latest versions of Windows 10 comes with OpenSSH `scp` built-in and it can be installed on older versions too.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using the Linux Ubuntu subsystem for Windows (you need to enable this as a Windows feature). Then you can use a Linux terminal client that runs on Windows by getting it from the Microsoft Store (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). Then, if you have ssh security set up to remote into your Linux machine, you can `scp` from your local Windows Ubuntu terminal (when logged in as the username that you set for your Linux instance) something like this:

`scp -i ~/.ssh/my_rsa username@11.11.11.11:~/myfile ~/`
... enter RSA passphrase

The remote file will be copied into your local Ubuntu filesystem used by Windows e.g.

`C:\Users\my.username\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu16.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\my_linux_username`

Comment: In the latest versions of Windows 10, (Win32-OpenSSH) `scp(.exe)` is built-in. You do not need to install anything.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else is in a very locked-down environment, and you can't even install PuTTY, here's what I do:

**Transferring files from Windows to Linux** (CentOS 7)

On my Windows computer, open a command prompt

```
scp [local file to send to Linux] [Linux username]@[Linux computer]:[Linux path to save to]
```

examples:

```
scp log.txt ryanLinuxUser@cent.xyz.com:/home/ryanLinuxUser
scp log.txt ryanLinuxUser@192.168.1.2:/home/ryanLinuxUser
```

**Transferring files from Linux to Windows**

Again on my Windows computer, open a command prompt

```
scp [Linux username]@[Linux computer]:[Linux path to existing file] [local Windows path to save to]
```

examples:

```
scp ryanLinuxUser@cent.xyz.com:/home/ryanLinuxUser/log.txt log.txt 
scp ryanLinuxUser@192.168.1.2:/home/ryanLinuxUser/log.txt log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

### on windows,scp file to my server:

> C:\Users\admin\Documents>scp Aaaa.docx tingfeng@192.168.1.223:/tmp

### on my server,scp from windows

```
scp admin@192.168.1.66:C:/Users/admin/Documents/Aaaa.docx /tmp
scp admin@192.168.1.66:"C:/Users/admin/Documents/Aaaa.docx" /tmp
```

### you can skip default prefix C:

> scp admin@192.168.1.66:/Users/admin/Documents/Aaaa.docx /tmp

Answer (score 0):

To copy a file from Linux to Windows, use the following command from Windows (no [Windows SSH server](https://www.howtogeek.com/336775/how-to-enable-and-use-windows-10s-built-in-ssh-commands/) required):

```sh
scp user@ip:/dir1/dir2/file "D:\dir1\dir2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the windows machine, open a CMD and enter the following:

```
scp linuxUsername@ip_address_of_linux_machine:~/Documents/testFile.txt ./
```

This way you don't need to "send" anything to your windows machine, instead you can "grab" the file from your linux machine.

The ./ specifies your current windows directory - you can change this if you want to copy to a specific directory, see below:

(Using made up values for better real life example)

```
scp ubuntuDesktop@192.168.1.25:~/Documents/testFile.txt /C:/Users/Max/Documents
```

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1: Download pscp**
https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html
(Based on your machine download the respective version)

**Step 2: Get familiar with the pscp commands**
To do so, open command prompt in your windows machine,  go to directory where you have downloaded pscp.exe and type "pscp"

**Step 3: Transfer file from your Linux machine to Windows machine**
open your command prompt, and run below command providing your details:

`pscp usernameofyourlinuxmachine@10.40.000.000:/path/of/your/File/nameofyourfile.txt ./`

and this command will transfer the file from your Linux machine to the current directory of your windows machine

**Step 4: Transfer file from your Windows machine to Linux machine**
open your command prompt, and run below command providing your details:

`pscp nameofyourfile.txt usernameofyourlinuxmachine@10.40.000.000:/path/where/youwantyourfile`

I hope this is clear and works for you all!

Comment: Link only answers are rather unhelpful as they may stop working in the future - try to expand your answer by actually explaining the steps in the video.

Answer (score -1):

Run this command to copy file from remote to local machine.

`scp username@ip:path_of_the_file Destination_path`

It will ask for credentials for the remote server.

Comment: What does your answer show that many of the existing answers do not show already?