# Copy data from a remote Linux box to my Windows desktop

Tags: linux, windows, putty, scp

I use Putty to login to the remote server and then set the environment and change the path to a particular directory. Now from this dir, I need to copy a folder to my desktop which is Windows?

How can I achieve this ?

Some of my failed attempts are as follows

```
scp -r remote_foldername srao@my_ipaddress:C:\srao\Users\Desktop
```

So from the remote server which is to be copied through putty, to my_username_in_windows@ip_address:path to destination

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off topic for StackOverflow. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more information about the types of questions that should be asked here. Voting to close as off topic and migrate to a more suitable site.

Comment: Please refer answer from here: [How to transfer files from Linux to Windows machine and vice versa](https://superuser.com/a/1214321/733512) Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [WinSCP](http://winscp.net). If you can ssh into a machine, it can transfer files.

Comment: Actually i found this right after posting the Qn and it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 6):

As Peter Lundgren suggests, [WinSCP](http://winscp.net) is a good choice -- for scp with a graphical user interface.

To copy from the *Windows* command line (not from the PuTTY shell on your remote Linux machine), PuTTY uses `pscp`.  You may have `pscp` already installed with PuTTY (e.g. in C:\Program Files\PuTTY or C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY), or it can be dowloaded from the [PuTTY Download Page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).  It uses syntax like standard `scp`:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY>pscp -r mylinuxuser@remotelinuxbox:/path/to/foldername C:\path\to\windows\destination
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options available here:

1. As pointed by Peter Lundgren and Lars Rohrbach, you can use winSCP - a GUI secure copy protocol tool
2. Another option would be to install cygwin on your windows machine and use `scp` to 'download/upload' files from your remote Linux host. e.g.

   ```
   scp -i /path/to/pem/file $SRC $DESTINATION
   ```
3. One drawback while using `scp` would be unavailability of resume support in case you face connection stallings. So you can use `rsync` with `--partial` flag. e.g.

   ```
   rsync --partial --progress -e "ssh -i /path/to/pem/file" user@host:/path/to/files/to/transfer /local/path
   ```