# Secure recursive copy from machine on different network to local machine running Cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin, file-transfer, openssh, scp

If I `ssh` from Cygwin into another machine that is on a different network, how do I conduct a recursive copy to my machine?

Comment: What type of logic are you currently using for this task or what did you have in mind to complete this task otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sftp` (or `scp`), not `ssh` to download files.

Withing `sftp`, use `get -r /remote/path /local/path` command.

If your question was how to initiate a transfer from an SSH terminal connected to a remote machine back to the local machine, you cannot. Of course unless you have an SSH server running on the local machine.
See also [How to SCP from linux server to Windows client](https://superuser.com/q/414803/213663).

Comment: Let's say remote is Username@Remotehost.com and I don't know what local is (a windows machine). How do I find out what local  is? Thanks. By the way, I am doing this on local on Cygwin.

Comment: Are you asking how to find a cygwin path for a given Windows path? Use `cygpath`.